# Image inside textblock c# windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to put an imagine inside a textblock inside a scrollviewer for my textblock. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have it as a background for my textblock and this is not even running. It compiles but it crashes.

```
<Image Source="Assets\picture.png" Margin="564,196,659,292" Grid.Row="1"/>
<ScrollViewer Height="645" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,113,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="627" Grid.RowSpan="2">
<TextBlock x:Name="tbl" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="627" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="22" > 
</TextBlock>
```

I get to see the image on the designer but it crashes... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Using Grid or canvas  we can place elements one over the other

```
 <ScrollViewer  x:Name="ScrollViewer">
  <Grid>
  <Image Source="Assets\picture.png" />
  <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" /> 
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```